# Setting directory as variable in Shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ls

What I am trying to do is to count all the files in a directory using shell script.

For example, when execute the program,

```
./test.sh project
```

it should count all the files in the folder called "project".

But I am having trouble with the directory part.

What I have done so far is,

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=$1
count=ls $directory | wc -l
echo "$folder has $count files"
```

but it does not work... Can anyone blow up my confusion please?

Thanks!

Comment: Look up what `$(` `)` (or backticks) do.

Comment: It's called *command substitution*. If you are using bash, you should also familiarize yourself with *process substitution*.

Answer (score 1):

You have an incorrect syntax while setting the count, for running nested commands in `bash` you need to use command-substitution using `$(..)` which runs the commands in a sub-shell and returns the restult

```
count=$(ls -- "$directory" | wc -l)
```

But never parse `ls` output in scripts for any purpose, use the more general purpose `find` command

```
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f  | wc -l
```

Check more about what `$(..)` form [Wiki Bash Hackers - Command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst)

Comment: That should be `ls -- "$directory"` in case you're dealing with a directory whose name starts with `-`.

Comment: @melpomene: Not something I'm recommending as per my update, but will make the edit still

Comment: Thank you so much Inian, btw could you please tell me what "$" is?
Why do we put $ in front of (ls.....)?

Comment: @YooSungKyung: You should go through the link I shared

Comment: Thanks!
When I use count=$(ls -- "$directory" | wc -l),
the counted files are 4 but it should be 3, does it also count any hidden files?

Comment: and when I used "find" command, it actually counted expected value which was 3!

Comment: @YooSungKyung: That's why I mentioned, do not use `ls` output in scripts

Comment: @YooSungKyung: You could _accept_ the answer (tick mark on the answer) to mark the question resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=$1
count=`ls $directory | wc -l`

echo "$folder has $count files"
```